# vim: How to jump to definition in external C header file

Tags: vim

I'm browsing some C code.
I ran into a variable that is defined in a header file.
How can i move my cursor under this variable and jump to see its definition ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Achieving this in vim can be done by using a tag file.

You can generate a tag file with the `ctags` or `exhuberant-ctags` program.

*cd* in the directory of your project and run:

```
ctags -R
```

This will generate a file named `tags` that contain a list of all symbols in your source code, with their location.

Vim knows how to use these files to get you to the correct location. When your cursor is over a symbol, just hit `CTRL-]` to get to its definition. And you can return where you were by hitting `CTRL-T`.

See `:help tags`, `:help CTRL-]` and `:help CTRL-T`

Vim can use multiple tag files at the same time. For example you could have one for your project and one for each library you use. For this, just generate the various tag files and add them in the `tags` setting:

```
set tags=./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS,/mytags/library1,/mytags/library2
```

`./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS` is the default value for `tags`; it searches for `tags` or `TAGS` in the current directory and in the directory of the current file.

Comment: Thank you. So I don't need any plugins ?

Comment: Also I need to run the ctags program everytime there's new files added or changed ?

Comment: That's builtin vim :) You'll just need the ctags program, that's not part of vim (it should be available in your package manager).

Comment: Yes, you have to update the ctags file manually each time you create new symbols or move them in other files

Comment: I've tried the ctags program but it doesn't seem to generate tags for the external header file. For example, Varible XX is defined in /usr/include/lib.h, but after running ctags -R, it didn't create tag for it.

Comment: Yes, you would have to generate a tag file for /usr/include too; place the tags file somewhere and add it the `tags` option: `set tags=./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS,/tag/file/for/usr/include`

Comment: The case is sometimes, you want to jump to the function declaration which the header files is not under the same folder of your source code. You can’t because ctags won’t know where is the function call come from.
With simple trick, you can make wonders. create a synlink under the folder of your source code to link to a specific directory or header files. Let say I wanna refers the curses.h which is located at /usr/include/, I can create a symlink in my source code folder.
ln -s /usr/include/curses.h curses.h

Comment: Look at ctags options, I think it can generate absolute path names too :)

Comment: hi, If my code is Java or Python file, can I use ctags to jump to the function defined on other file?

Comment: This answer is now 10 years old. Is there any new options? I don't like using `ctags`...